# Hidden NavBar reappears when tap occurs ios

Tags: ios8, uinavigationbar, hidden

This should be an easy one and I hope that someone could explain it to me.

When I set hidesBarsOnSwipe or navbarhidden it's working very well. The navBar hide but when I press a button or anything else the navbar shows up again.
I understand that it's a "normal behaviour" to not block the navigation experience.
But what if I want the navbar to stay hide and only show on swipe?

Thx

Comment: What' the piece of code that you use to hide navbar?

Comment: I'm using the basic:
self.hidesBarsOnSwipe = Yes;

Comment: What about using `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true` in swift.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really use or understand Swift langage yet. Could You explain the logic to me in objC? Thanks a lot though